# SQLAlchemy can't use func.bigger as func in query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

To desc my problem. Can see this raw sql:

```
select datediff(now(), create_time) > 7 as is_new from test order by is_new desc limit 19;
```

I try to implement by SQLAlchemy step by step:

```
diff_days = func.datediff(today, test.create_time).label("diff_days")
session.query(diff_days).filter(test.id.in_((1,2,3,33344))).order_by(diff_days.asc()).all()
```

This work fine. But when I want to desc `>` in mysql. It failed:

```
is_new = func.greater(func.datediff(today, test.create_time), 7).label("is_new")
session.query(is_new).filter(test.id.in_((1,2,3,33344))).order_by(is_new.asc()).all()
```

I know SQLAlchemy explain my sql to `greater` while mysql don't support. So How can I to get my answer `a > b` with something like `greater(a, b)`

May be the simple sql `select a > b from test`   can desc the problem too. While above is my origin need. So the problem can change :

How to using SQLAIchemy orm to implement `select a > b from test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy offers you [rich operator overloading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.__gt__), so just do

```
is_new = (func.datediff(today, test.create_time) > 7).label("is_new")
session.query(is_new).\
    filter(test.id.in_([1, 2, 3, 33344])).\
    order_by(is_new.asc()).\
    all()
```

This works since the created [`Function`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function) is also a [`ColumnElement`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement) and as such has [`ColumnOperators`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I am looking for. It return `True` or `False` not mysql's `1` or `0` while never mind. I can transform later.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "It return `True` or `False`, not ...". The whole `(func.datediff(...) > 7)` results in a new SQL binary expression object that'll be part of your query and evaluated in the DB.

Comment: somthing like `[(True,), (True,), (True,), (True,)]` not `[(1,),(1,)....]`

Comment: Ah that. Yeah, SQLA figures that the comparison should result in a boolean, so it'll convert the result from the DB for you.