# Flask-SQLAlchemy, subtract two dates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask-SQLAlchemy and using ORMs in general. I'm trying to subtract two dates and see if they're equal or less than a certain integer. I have the query working in plain SQL but struggling with finding how to do this in SQLAlchemy. Here's my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE DATEDIFF(expiration, NOW()) <= 2
```

This query works perfectly but I need it to work with SQLAlchemy. I've looked Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy documentation with no luck. Any help/direction is appreciated as I've spent more time than I'd like on this.

Comment: `func.datediff(..., func.now())`, see here for a similar construct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44276883/2681632